# FedEx "Service INTERNATIONAL_GROUND is invalid" message

Tags: soap, service, fedex

i made integration with FedEx web services. All things works like a charm, but when i try to use international ground service type it raised me this error "Service INTERNATIONAL_GROUND is invalid" error N782. What could be the problem? FedEx support told me that i used dropoff type "DROP_BOX" and this causes the error, but i tried to change that to all 5 variants without success. I sent them a ticket, but still no answer.

Here is the SOAP request i send:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:ns1="http://fedex.com/ws/rate/v9">
    <SOAP-ENV:Body>
        <ns1:RateRequest>
            <ns1:WebAuthenticationDetail>
                <ns1:UserCredential>
                    <ns1:Key>my key</ns1:Key>
                    <ns1:Password>my pass</ns1:Password>
                </ns1:UserCredential>
            </ns1:WebAuthenticationDetail>
            <ns1:ClientDetail>
                <ns1:AccountNumber>acc number</ns1:AccountNumber>
                <ns1:MeterNumber>metter number</ns1:MeterNumber>
            </ns1:ClientDetail>
            <ns1:TransactionDetail>
                <ns1:CustomerTransactionId>SearchFit Shopping Cart v8.20.5 (Sep 27, 2011)</ns1:CustomerTransactionId>
            </ns1:TransactionDetail>
            <ns1:Version>
                <ns1:ServiceId>crs</ns1:ServiceId>
                <ns1:Major>9</ns1:Major>
                <ns1:Intermediate>0</ns1:Intermediate>
                <ns1:Minor>0</ns1:Minor>
            </ns1:Version>
            <ns1:ReturnTransitAndCommit>true</ns1:ReturnTransitAndCommit>
            <ns1:RequestedShipment>
                <ns1:ShipTimestamp>2011-09-28T01:15:54+03:00</ns1:ShipTimestamp>
                <ns1:ServiceType>INTERNATIONAL_GROUND</ns1:ServiceType>
                <ns1:PackagingType>YOUR_PACKAGING</ns1:PackagingType>
                <ns1:TotalInsuredValue>
                    <ns1:Currency>USD</ns1:Currency>
                </ns1:TotalInsuredValue>
                <ns1:Shipper>
                    <ns1:Address>
                        <ns1:StateOrProvinceCode>GA</ns1:StateOrProvinceCode>
                        <ns1:PostalCode>30030</ns1:PostalCode>
                        <ns1:CountryCode>US</ns1:CountryCode>
                    </ns1:Address>
                </ns1:Shipper>
                <ns1:Recipient>
                    <ns1:Address>
                        <ns1:PostalCode>HP10</ns1:PostalCode>
                        <ns1:CountryCode>GB</ns1:CountryCode>
                        <ns1:Residential>true</ns1:Residential>
                    </ns1:Address>
                </ns1:Recipient>
                <ns1:ShippingChargesPayment>
                    <ns1:PaymentType>SENDER</ns1:PaymentType>
                    <ns1:Payor>
                        <ns1:AccountNumber>acc number</ns1:AccountNumber>
                        <ns1:CountryCode>US</ns1:CountryCode>
                    </ns1:Payor>
                </ns1:ShippingChargesPayment>
                <ns1:RateRequestTypes>ACCOUNT</ns1:RateRequestTypes>
                <ns1:PackageCount>1</ns1:PackageCount>
                <ns1:PackageDetail>INDIVIDUAL_PACKAGES</ns1:PackageDetail>
                <ns1:RequestedPackageLineItems>
                    <ns1:Weight>
                        <ns1:Units>LB</ns1:Units>
                        <ns1:Value>10.0</ns1:Value>
                    </ns1:Weight>
                    <ns1:Dimensions>
                        <ns1:Length>5</ns1:Length>
                        <ns1:Width>11</ns1:Width>
                        <ns1:Height>8</ns1:Height>
                        <ns1:Units>IN</ns1:Units>
                    </ns1:Dimensions>
                </ns1:RequestedPackageLineItems>
            </ns1:RequestedShipment>
        </ns1:RateRequest>
    </SOAP-ENV:Body>
</SOAP-ENV:Envelope>
```

And here is the response:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
    <env:Header xmlns:env="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"/>
    <soapenv:Body>
        <v9:RateReply xmlns:v9="http://fedex.com/ws/rate/v9">
            <v9:HighestSeverity xmlns:env="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">ERROR</v9:HighestSeverity>
            <v9:Notifications xmlns:env="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
                <v9:Severity>ERROR</v9:Severity>
                <v9:Source>crs</v9:Source>
                <v9:Code>782</v9:Code>
                <v9:Message>Service INTERNATIONAL_GROUND is invalid.</v9:Message>
                <v9:LocalizedMessage>Service INTERNATIONAL_GROUND is invalid.</v9:LocalizedMessage>
                <v9:MessageParameters>
                    <v9:Id>SERVICE_TYPE</v9:Id>
                    <v9:Value>INTERNATIONAL_GROUND</v9:Value>
                </v9:MessageParameters>
            </v9:Notifications>
            <ns1:TransactionDetail xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:ns1="http://fedex.com/ws/rate/v9">
                <ns1:CustomerTransactionId>SearchFit Shopping Cart v8.20.5 (Sep 27, 2011)</ns1:CustomerTransactionId>
            </ns1:TransactionDetail>
            <ns1:Version xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:ns1="http://fedex.com/ws/rate/v9">
                <ns1:ServiceId>crs</ns1:ServiceId>
                <ns1:Major>9</ns1:Major>
                <ns1:Intermediate>0</ns1:Intermediate>
                <ns1:Minor>0</ns1:Minor>
            </ns1:Version>
        </v9:RateReply>
    </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

Comment: Depending on the origin and destination of the shipment, INTERATIONAL_GROUND may not be the correct service level. Where are you shipping from/to? Have you tried using just FEDEX_GROUND?

Comment: No, this is not from the addresses, The example is from USA/Georgia 30030 to Canada/Alberta T0A0A0. Notice that other international services are working as a charm.

Comment: I'm pretty sure that shipments within North America should all be treated as FEDEX_GROUND. I'd try using that.

Comment: I used that but it said me "Service is not allowed." In their online calculator they showed only 2 services for same locations both international, and one of them - international ground

Comment: For now they respond me that this type service isn't supported in their system. So sad because their documentation says the opposite. I'm waiting for their next response about how to use FEDEX_GROUND for international shipment (CANADA-MEXICO, or FRANCE-GERMANY for example)

Comment: Not surprising to me. The implementation I completed with FedEx invovled a good bit of trial-and-error to get things working properly. Good luck!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a week of waiting i got the response from them. In short:

FedEx International Ground is a direct-ship method for you to send single or multi-weight small package shipments directly from the U.S. to Canada, Canada to the U.S. There are no minimum package requirements.

They doesn't support international ground even their documentation tells the opposite.

Comment: Here is a list of most available options for the SERVICE_TYPE parameter: http://www.fedex.com/us/developer/product/WebServices/MyWebHelp/Transactions/WS/r_ServiceAvailabilityReplyElements.html, the rest can be found from this link: http://www.fedex.com/us/developer/product/WebServices/MyWebHelp/Services/c_GlobalDomesticShipping.html.

In my code I narrowed the list to the following common types: FEDEX_GROUND, PRIORITY_OVERNIGHT, INTERNATIONAL_PRIORITY, INTERNATIONAL_ECONOMY since the target audience lives in US/Canada.

Answer (score 0):

In your request, the recipient has a country code of GB, which is not Canada.  That probably explains why international ground is not coming back as a valid shipping option.

Comment: Men, i spoke with them and they told me that they don't support international ground service. Only support US to Canada. But if i want to send a package from Germany to France (for example) via internationall ground service it will retun me an error "Unsupported service"